# Call async function while pushing the same function on array

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have this code:

```
var queue = [];
var allParserd = [];

_.each(webs, function (web) {
    queue.push(function () {
        WebsitesUtils.parseWebsite(web, function (err, parsed) {
            allParserd.push(parsed);
        });
    });
});

Promise.all(queue).then(function (data) {
    console.log(allParserd);
});
```

Basically I need to fetch all my webs and be sure to give the result after that every parsing is done. the function `parseWebsite` return the correct data, but in this way is not called and `allParsed` return just as an empty array. I'm sure that I miss some things, I've started to use the promises just from some days.

If you need some more information just tell me.

P.s. 
I want that all the functions to start at the same time; I don't want to wait for each one response for going forward.

Comment: Your parseWebsite function should really be refactored to return a promise, mixing callbacks and Promises can be confusing. Once you've done that you can take advantage of the Promise.map/Promise.each functions etc that the likes of Bluebird provide.

Comment: What `Promise` library are you using?

Comment: Bluebird, i will add a tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Promise.all`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise) doesn't take a queue of functions to execute. It expects an *array of promises* which represent the results of the many concurrently running (still pending) requests.

The first step is to have a function that actually returns a promise, instead of only executing a callback. We can use

```
function parseWebsite(web) {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        WebsitesUtils.parseWebsite(web, function (err, parsed) {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                fulfill(parsed);
        });
    });
}
```

or simply use [promisification](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) that does this generically:

```
var parseWebsite = Promise.promisify(WebsitesUtils.parseWebsite, WebsitesUtils);
```

Now we can go to construct our array of promises by calling that function for each site:

```
var promises = [];
_.each(webs, function (web) {
    promises.push(parseWebsite(web));
});
```

or just

```
var promises = _.map(webs, parseWebsite);
```

so that in the end we can use `Promise.all`, and get back our `allParsed` array (which even is in the same order as `webs` was!):

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(allParsed) {
    console.log(allParsed);
});
```

Bluebird even provides a shortcut function so you don't need `promises`:

```
Promise.map(webs, parseWebsite).then(function(allParsed) {
    console.log(allParsed);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful explanation, i was missing the part that i needed an array of promises and not of functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Tagged with Bluebird so let's use it:

First, let's convert your callback API to promises:

```
  Promise.promisifyAll(WebsitesUtils);
```

Now, let's use `.map` to map every item in webs to it being parsed parseWebsite:

```
Promise.map(webs, function(item){
    return WebsitesUtils.parseWebsiteAsync(item); // note the suffix
}).then(function(results){
    // all the results are here.
}).catch(function(err){
    // handle any errors
});
```

As you can see - this is trivial to do with Bluebird.

Comment: Thank for your reply, this solution works too, i've marked the other one as solution just because there are also a general example, other than only Bluebird. Thanks again

Comment: @DannoEterno if you want to learn more about how promisification works see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises :)

Comment: Also, if Bergi's solution solves your problem by all means do upvote it. The Promise tag is relatively small and the faster Bergi (and other tag regs like jfriend and esailija) gets to a gold badge the better it is for us since he gets more moderation privileges :)

Comment: Yeah, i know, but i don't have reputation on stackoverflow to give the upvote that he deserve. I've always lurked without the possibility to upvote every solution that i've found on SO :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's how might do it with [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
var async = require('async');

var webs = ...

async.map(webs, function(web, callback) {
  WebsitesUtils.parseWebsite(web, callback);
}, function(err, results) {
  if (err) throw err; // TODO: handle errors better

  // `results` contains all parsed results
});
```

and if `parseWebsite()` isn't a prototype method dependent on `WebsitesUtils` then you could simplify it further:

```
async.map(webs, WebsitesUtils.parseWebsite, function(err, results) {
  if (err) throw err; // TODO: handle errors better

  // `results` contains all parsed results
});
```

Comment: Hi mscdex, thanks for your reply. The first solution seems don't work, WebsitesUtils is never called (and it don't return either an error) and i cannot use the second one because is dependent from WebsitesUtils.